# How to send data from Firebase to Android/iOS Application and Python

Tags: python, android, ios, firebase, server

I am currently developing an Android and iOS application that uses Machine Learning.
This app sends data from the mobile application to the server(most probably Firebase).
Meanwhile, the machine learning model would be pre-trained using Python.

In order for this application to work, the data sent from the mobile app should be sent to Python from the server. After the data goes into the pre-trained model, a specific output would be produced and the output would be sent back to the mobile app.
However, there would be a huge memory usage as Python should be infinitely run to retrieve the updated data from Firebase.

Is it possible to send data from Firebase to Python and mobile applications once data has been updated in the Firebase? If it is not possible in Firebase, are there any other servers that can implement this function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to send data from Firebase to Python and mobile applications once data has been updated in the Firebase?

Yes it is possible you have to set up Firebase Admin SDK, check documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).